# Is there a Speech to text from voice file for Android?

Tags: android, speech

So I've looked at some of the posts here and ore mother sites and since times change quickly in our world would like to know if there is any SDK or API out there yet that will essentially take an audio file and convert it to text ?

I realize anything's possible, especially in open source, but I'm just too new to this environment. So if anyone had any insights or links inepildnao appreciate it.

Many thanks ahead as always.

Answer (score -1):

You can start using simple Speech to text that appears in a list.
Then you can "play" with that list and try new things.
Here I leave you a perfect tutorial [Here](https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/android-speech-recognition-example.html)

I leave the link because you didnt ask about code , so there it is.

Comment: I appreciate the help. But I am looking for something that will work off of a recorded voice file and not "live"